# What does this mean (second part of the sentence)?

Tags: translation

もう片方は、ビニールのカバーがありませんが、**箱は中古感が少なく、
綺麗です。**

What is the second part of the sentence in bold?

Comment: What specifically do you have trouble understanding about it?

Answer (score 1):

It means;

the box looks like relatively new and clean

I think the writer wants to communicate this box doesn't
look like as old as it is.